# How to add a template folder to the Django project ? (in pycharm community edition)

Tags: django, django-templates, pycharm

How to add a template folder to the Django project ?(in pycharm community edition)?

Comment: Please see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/templates.html (This is a Professional feature: download PyCharm Professional to try.)

Comment: you can see django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/overriding-templates/ and also refer youtube tutorial those will tell it directly

Comment: Thanks  s0xzwasd, but this is for the commercial version pycharm, not the free version.

Answer (score 0):

you can see [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/overriding-templates/) also refer youtube tutorial those will tell it directly

create a template folder manually and add path base_dir here  are some links you'll find solution

[LINK1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNlIe5zvBeQ) [LINK2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kz-G6GnumsI&t=3s)

let me know if it work or not

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I work with the free version of Paycharm. And most of the tutorials are related to the commercial version of Payarm.

Comment: see its not my job but i would suggest to use VS code it is so comfortable as far as i have used i haven't got any issue and also it is easy to solve you issue in it i would suggest to

Comment: Switch IDE and if you dont want then i am editing my answer just

Comment: Thanks Vishal Pandey, other friends have suggested me the VS code. I downloaded it too, but I haven't used it much yet.

Comment: Thanks Vishal Pandey,
I realized that working with Django is not dependent on the IDE, and we can even create our project without the IDE in the first place.
I found the answer to my question in the following link. This tutorial does not use pycharm, but this method can also be applied to pycharm.

Comment: Glad to help your Welcome And yes django don't depend on ide

Answer (score 0):

add a template folder to the Django project:
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iy4niMCsbEE)